# Rails Controller knowing which action brought me here

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The scenario is this:
I have 2 Model-View-Controllers , A and B.

In A's index.html.erb, I have a link to B's new.html.erb, that looks like /a/1/b/new. B can also be displayed by doing /b/new.

In B's new method is there a way to tell I got there from a?

I need to do if came from A, do some, otherwise don't.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the refer

```
refer_hash = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)
```

now you can check the previous controller by

```
refer_hash[:controller]
```

and action by

```
refer_hash[:action]
```

So in the end you will have code like

```
refer_hash = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)
if refer_hash[:action] == 'index' && refer_hash[:controller] == 'A'
    # Do something
else
    # Do something else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your action is processing the request with A resource, you should be able to retrieve the a_id in the params hash. Here is the method I often use in my app:

```
class BController < ApplicationController
    def new
       if params[:a_id].present?
           #do something with A here
       else
           #do something otherwise
       end
    end
end
```

If you want to be sure, run `rake routes` in your console to see how the requests look like. I imagine you would see a route like this:

```
a/:a_id/b/new
```

and another route like this

```
/b/new
```

Comment: I solved it by check for checking in B Controller, params[:a_id]. If navigation is /a/1/b/new a.id param should exists. Seems correct ?

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested :)

Comment: If my answer is correct, can you mark it as answer? :)

Comment: That technically does not tell what previous controller is. If you  accidently set params[:a_id] in the form of A or B, then you cannot tell them apart. You also should not rely on params to check the previous, because users can easily edit the form html and add a_id

Answer (score 0):

**FYI**

If you'd like to know the name of your controller & action, you can use the two Rails helpers called [`action_name` (now `action` it seems)](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionController/Metal/action/class) and [`controller_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class)

Whether this will help you directly, I'm not sure

--

**Referral**

> In B's new method is there a way to tell I got there from a?

I don't know if this will solve your issue as well as `@sonnyhe2002`'s answer, but if you're requesting `B` from a [`nested resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), you could play with the `params` hash to achieve the functionality  you desire

If your routes are like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :a do
   resources :b #-> domain.com/a/:a_id/b/new
end
```

This will mean if you render the `b#new` action as part of your nested route, you will have the variable `params[:a_id]` available, which means you'll be able to test if it's there in your `b` controller action:

```
#app/controllers/b_controller.rb
def new
   if params[:a_id]
      # logic
   else
      # logic
   end
end
```

It's a different way of looking at it